# jQuery validation error message

Tags: jquery, validation, message

I am using jQuery validation plugin  and I want that the error message to be displayed in a specific text input with id="test".

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Validation Plugin documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options):

```
$(".selector").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
      var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
      if (errors) {
        var message = errors == 1
          ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
          : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
        $("div.error span").html(message);
        $("div.error").show();
      } else {
        $("div.error").hide();
      }
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), you could find out if you have any errors by querying [numberOfInvalids( )](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/numberOfInvalids)

```
var validator = $("#myform").validate({
  invalidHandler: function() {
    $("#summary").text(validator.numberOfInvalids() + " field(s) are invalid");
  }
});
```

and if you have any, you could then go through the elements in your form individually

```
$("#myform").validate().element( "#myselect" );
```

This code returns a boolean as to whether the element is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.appendTo( $('input#test'));
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#myform").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $('input#test').val(error);
        }
    });
```

Although, I'm not sure why you'd want to populate an input field with the validation error, but i'm sure it makes sense on the front end you're designing.